# HTML, inability to autoplay audio file in background by hiding player in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <section>
     <video src="smoke.mp4" autoplay muted></video>


 
    
    
    <div id="player">
    <audio autoplay hidden>
     <source src="Playstation 4 StartUp Sound Effect.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> #PROBLEM
                
    </audio>
</div>
    
    <h1>
       <span>W</span>
       <span>E</span>
       <span>L</span>
       <span>C</span>
       <span>O</span>
       <span>M</span>
       <span>E</span>
    </h1> 
   </section>


<style>


body 
  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background:black;
  }

section
  {
  height:100vh;
  background:#000; 
  

  }

video
  {
  object-fit:cover;
  }
   
h1
 {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 color:#ddd;
 font-size:5em;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 letter-spacing:0.2em;

 }

h1 span
 {
 display:inline-block;
 animation: animate 1s linear forwards;

 }

@keyframes animate
 {
 
 0%
 { 
  opacity:0;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  filter:blur(10px);
 }

100%
 { 
  opacity:1;
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
   filter:blur(0px);
 }

 }


h1 span:nth-child(1)
{
 
 animation-delay: 1s;

}
    

h1 span:nth-child(2)
{
 
 animation-delay: 1.5s;

}

h1 span:nth-child(3)
{
 
 animation-delay: 2s;

}

h1 span:nth-child(4)
{
 
 animation-delay: 2.5s;

}

h1 span:nth-child(5)
{
 
 animation-delay: 3s;

}

h1 span:nth-child(6)
{
 
 animation-delay: 3.75s;

}

h1 span:nth-child(7)
{
 
 animation-delay: 4s;

}


    
</style>
     

</body>


  


<script>
document
  .querySelector('video')
  .addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    e.target.style.display = 'none';
  });

</script>
</html>
```

When the welcome message starts to appear on the screen, I want the player to play the audio file in the background without appearing, but what I added does not work. How can I solve this problem?
Additionally, Is it possible to set the speed of the player to default? I have to speed it up so that the text and the music are in sync

The Sound file link: https://djlunatique.com/playstation-4-start-up-sound-effect/

The video file link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ncI67cgjRGoQZHF6I0dEpXwvFwCKxFPK/view

Browser version: Chrome 108.0.5359.99

Answer (score 0):

I´ve tried your code and it seems to work, [see here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ps4-audio-proyect-gqbc42)

Maybe there was a problem with the spaces on the file name, also, there´s a simple way to change the video/audio speed with the playbackRate property in JS (speed 1 is default). For example:

```
<div id="player">
        <audio class="myAudio" autoplay hidden>
        <!--Add the class "myAudio"-->
          <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
          #PROBLEM
        </audio>
</div>
<script>
      let audio = document.querySelector(".myAudio");
      <!--Select the audio element-->
      audio.playbackRate = 2;
      <!--Set the speed to 2x-->
</script>
```

All this code is in the page I linked before, so you can easily change the speed and copy-paste

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, Google Chrome has a special error that affects the mp3 files, if the audio doesn´t work I recommend you to try it in another browsers (or maybe change your audio format type).